# Avoid error reading characters of string. char *

Tags: c++, c++11

I look over several similar question, but I couldn't find the proper solution for my situation. I am trying to do a omp parallel loop. Inside one of my functions in the parallel region, I am trying to create m_buffer which I guess 
is shared (it is a very huge and complicated piece of code, I am a user).

```
//Vector of pointers, each of which points to the start of some one-way list of free elements of same size.
//The size of the elements in each list  is determined by list's index in the vector, 
//namely the size of the element is (sizeof(void) * (index + 1)).
std::vector<char*> m_buffer;
...
bufIdx = i_element_size / sizeof(void*) - 1;
...
if (m_buffer[bufIdx] == nullptr)
{
...
}
else
{
//comes here!
}
```

Apparently one thread tries to allocate an element inside the buffer at index of 0. Attached to this question you will see the buffer in debug using vs 2013. 
I am wondering if there is a way to detect the situation beside if condition.

[image]

Comment: Are you protecting the vector contents in your methods using mutex?

Comment: Could you please post more code. What is i_element_size? How did you fill m_buffer?

Comment: @Unick , i_element_size is an int which is the argument of function.

Comment: @seccpur, no and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: this can be just an unallocated pointer inside the buffer after creating the vector. And no you cannot detect that. That is why in c++ people always tell you to initialize your variables. using e.g. `std::string` instead of `char*` would directly initialize the values to an empty string and not just some random pointer. Though this can also be a already deleted object and not setting the pointer inside to `nullptr` afterwards

Comment: "Apparently one thread" - Apparently?  You should know if you're working with a multi-threaded application or not!

Comment: @UKMonkey As I said it is in the parallel region, and as I am trying to parallelise a for loop. My Question is that is this situation detectable beforehand?

Comment: when you insert or delete items from the vector, the vector iterators in your worker threads may be in undefined state which will lead to error. Read topics on std::mutex and implement to avoid problems with multithreading